# Twilio - escalation system

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm new to twilio and I'm looking to set up an escalation system.

Today we use functionTWIML to manage calls.

Still in the functions, I would like if the number called does not answer (after 10-15s), it redirects to another number, if this one does not answer, it calls 2-3 numbers simultaneously.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the `sequential` parameter discussed here. It will work for different types of endpoints, including PSTN. Make sure your Twilio Helper libraries are a more current release and this feature is enabled as discussed in the Blog post.

If you have voice mail issues, you must take a different path similar to a blog post such as [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions) (additional [details](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/changelog)) to understand how to navigate around those.

[Sequential Dialing Functions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/blind-transfer-sip-multidial-programmable-voice)